# Rails 3 model generator with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a model called `User`. Is there any options in `rails generator` command line to add associations to the models will be generated. For example I want to create a new model called `Pet` and I want pets belongs to `User` and `User` has many `Pets`. Is there any option to automatically generate those associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not all the things you wanted but below command generates belongs_to association.

```
rails generate Model Pet user:references
```

It will also create `user_id` field in pets table for association.
You have to add `has_many` to User model manually.